# Is it correct to say "an auspicious situation"?

Tags: word-usage

Auspicious, as defined by Merriam-Webster means - showing or suggesting that future success is likely. I was learning about the correct usage of the word and found the following usages to be correct :

- auspicious occasion/beginning/start/moment/symbol/place/debut

Nowhere did I find someone mentioning "auspicious situation". Is this usage with "situation" correct?

Comment: Why do you think there might be a problem? About [832 writers in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22auspicious+situation%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) are happy to use this two-word collocation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers My impression is that *auspicious* is nowadays more often used in its antonym form *inauspicious*, than in the positive. Even Oxford Dictionaries (not OED) gave as its first example: *it was not the most auspicious moment to hold an election*. It did also give an example about an *auspicious moon rising*, but frankly I would have struggled to recall an example of its positive use.

Comment: @WS2: Comparing the relative prevalence of *auspicious/inauspicious* in Google Books, I can't see any evidence of a usage shift. I do have the general sense that "common speech" tends to be more sarcastic/negative today than in our (almost forgotten! :) younger days, so I can kinda see where you're coming from. But most of today's young pups probably couldn't ascertain the meaning of a word like *auspicious* even if you gave them a full paper copy of OED, so I wouldn't take too much notice of their "pre-literate grunts". (Or should that be "post-literate", as we live in "the latter days"? :)

Answer (score 1):

As this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=auspicious%20situation&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Causpicious%20situation%3B%2Cc0) shows, the phrase *auspicious situation* regularly appears in literature. The pattern suggests that such usage was more frequent in the nineteenth century.

However, all of your alternatives are much more common, as shown in this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=auspicious%20situation%2Causpicious%20occasion%2Causpicious%20beginning%2C%20auspicious%20start%2C%20auspicious%20moment%2C%20auspicious%20symbol%2C%20auspicious%20place%2C%20auspicious%20debut&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Causpicious%20situation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Causpicious%20occasion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Causpicious%20beginning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Causpicious%20start%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Causpicious%20moment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Causpicious%20symbol%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Causpicious%20place%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Causpicious%20debut%3B%2Cc0).